# How can I use a list declared in two different classes in another class, without using interface in C#?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, class, console-application

I have two similar classes A and B, which contain the following code:

```
//A or B depending on class
public class LogicA
    {
        public List<Members> MembersA { get; set; } = new List<Member>();

        public void AddMember(Member member)
        {
            MembersA.Add(member);
        }

        public List<Member> GetResultA()
        {
            return MembersA;
        }

    }
```

I want to use the MembersA and MembersB lists in another class (say logicC).
I have seen similar questions and they mostly involve single inheritance. The process I thought to use was to create instance of lists from two different classes in the third class through multiple inheritance but in C#, only interface support multiple inheritance and I am using classes, hence my issue.

Comment: The members of both lists are of type Member so I dont see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason that you need to use inheritance only?

Generally, the way of using a member of Class is follow

```
class logicC
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    LogicA logicA = new LogicA();
    LogicB logicB = new LogicB();

    List<Member> memberA =  logicA.memberA;
    List<Member> memberB =  logicB.memberB;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `static` modifier for your methods for example:

```
public static class LogicA
{
    public static List<Members> MembersA { get; set; } = new List<Member>();

    public static void AddMember(Member member)
    {
        MembersA.Add(member);
    }

    public static List<Member> GetResultA()
    {
        return MembersA;
    }

}
```

and use this like that:

```
using YourProject;

public class LogicC
{
   Members members = new();
   List<Members> membersList = new();
   LogicA.AddMember(member);
   membersList = LogicA.GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Both `Logica.GetResultA` and presumably  `LogicB.GetResultB` return `List<Member>`. So there is no problem

LogicC can be

```
class LogicC{
   void NoodleOnList(List<Member> input){
       ....
   }
}
```

then

```
   LogicC lc;
   lc.NoodelOnList(la.GetMembersA());
   lc.NoodelOnList(lb.GetMembersb());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Well, you should re-consider your design choices and think about how to make your code less prone to change*.

You can create a new class to aggregate Lists from A, B. And via Composition this new class might access Lists from other inner objects.

```
public class logicC {
   public LogicA logicA;
   public LogicB logicB;

   public List<Member> GetResultC() => logicA.GetResultA().Concat(logicB.GetResultB());
}
```